# Configure ElasticSearch attachment mapper to use OCR plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, tesseract, elasticsearch-plugin

I installed elastic search with the attachment mapper then installed tesseract OCR on the same machine, my goal is to be able to index images through elastic search.

currently I'm able to parse and index Microsoft office files with elastic but not images as in someway elastic needs to know that tesseract is installed on the machine and pass the image to it to extract the text.

tesseract installation is fine as i can use it as standalone, any help making it work with elastic?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand your question.  Your set up / context, desired behavior, and problem are tangled up in a single paragraph that's hard to understand.  Can you try to explain more clearly?

Comment: I just did, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

tesseract is already enabled in [Apache Tika](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaOCR). So you could use the Elasticsearch [Ingest Attachment plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest-attachment.html) to index your images with active OCR in Tika.

I only managed to enable OCR in Tika using an additional properties file located in the class path at `/org/apache/tika/parser/ocr/TesseractOCRConfig.properties` . Configured are languages and tesseract location:

```
language=deu+eng
tesseractPath=D:\programs\Tesseract-OCR
```

So basically, all you need to do is to create the directory structure holding the properties file and add this to your class path.

Hope this helps

Konrad.